# Unknown module "Firebase" in React native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am working on some sample apps using react native. I am trying to integrate Firebase plugin followed by [firebase tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-29-react-native.html).

I can able to add firebase plugin using

```
npm install firebase --save
```

It gets added to node_modules, when i try to require the plugin

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
```

It throws an exceptions **"Requiring unknown module 'firebase'...."**

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the packager?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for response. Restart package mean running command react-native run-android ? and even i reload js too. nothing reflect

Comment: Check that firebase is actually present in `node_modules`. I don't know what your _packager_ is, but if you're sure you've restarted it, and you're sure firebase is installed, consider deleting `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: I'm having this issue too, it's more related to how Firebase has setup their module and the fact it breaks on react-native.

Comment: @ArneHugo Yeah firebase is there in node_modules. Its added. but cant able require firebase variable

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've installed the dependency with:

```
npm install firebase --save
```

(make sure you are in your project folder)

Then end the NPM process and restart by running `react-native start`. That should do the trick.